# Definition of a rational map between projective varieties.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ and $Y\subset\mathbb{P}^m$ be projective varieties. If $m$ homogeneous polynomials in $n+1$ variables of the same degree give a partially defined map from $X$ to $Y$ then this map is called a rational map.

My question is why do some people insist in the definition of a rational map that $X$ be irreducible?

Answer (score 5):

Irreducible varieties have a function fields (the stalk at the generic point in scheme language), and it is a useful fact that rational maps correspond 1:1 to homomorphisms between the function fields. But of course the definition of a rational map doesn't require any assumption, and in fact, works for arbitrary varieties/schemes. A quite general treatment can be found in the [Stacks Project, 24.10](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01RR).